# Cannot find module create-react-app/script/start.js

Tags: reactjs

something has changed in my program structure and due to its complexity i cannot exactly point where the problem. Ever since my application crushed and no longer working  i have tried different approaches like deleting the node module packages and reinstalling them but still wont work.
whenever i try to run **npm start** i get the following errors:

[image]

below is my project structure
[image]

And below is my **package.json** file

```
   {
    "name": "events-react-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.1",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint": "4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
   "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
   "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
   "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
   "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
   "file-loader": "1.1.5",
   "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
   "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
   "object-assign": "4.1.1",
   "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
   "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
   "promise": "8.0.1",
   "raf": "3.4.0",
   "react": "^16.2.0",
   "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.0",
   "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
"style-loader": "0.19.0",
"sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
"url-loader": "0.6.2",
"webpack": "3.8.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "2.9.4",
"webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
"whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
},
 "scripts": {
 "start": "node scripts/start.js",
 "build": "node scripts/build.js",
 "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
},
 "jest": {
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
  "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
   ],
 "setupFiles": [
  "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
  ],
  "testMatch": [
  "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
  "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
],
   "testEnvironment": "node",
"testURL": "http://localhost",
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
  "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
  "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": " 
   <rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
},
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
],
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
},
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "web.js",
  "mjs",
  "js",
  "json",
  "web.jsx",
  "jsx",
  "node"
]
  },
   "babel": {
"presets": [
  "react-app"
]
},
  "eslintConfig": {
"extends": "react-app"
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you run `npm install` yet?

Comment: It sounds like `create-react-app` was used to create this application initially, and that `create-react-app` added a `scripts/` folder with scripts to run the project.  That `scripts/` folder should have been added to source control, so that checking it out again would result in it still being there.  You may need to use `create-react-app` again to get that `scripts/` folder back

Comment: yes, i have tried several times but still cannot make to work

Comment: your `package.json` has a `scripts` section, which lists `start` command as `node scripts/start.js`, but it seems like there is no file `scripts/start.js`.  When you run `npm start`, it just looks at that value and runs it.  You'll need to figure out where it originally came from, and get it back.

Comment: i tried to follow your lead to use create - react-app  to get the script folder back but cant see any folder named script

Comment: I got this error when trying to start a react app on a different computer (synced folder). The problem turned out to be that the dev server was already running on the first computer!

Comment: check all your import statements

Answer (score 52):

`react-scripts start` generates error `Error: Cannot find module '../scripts/start'`

I'm not sure what is causing the problem during the `create react app`, but the thing I found that works best is simply delete the `nodes_module` folder then in Terminal run `npm install` in the project directory.

Reference: [Npm start fails](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3690#issuecomment-357509475)

Comment: I did the same. The root cause of the issue was, I copied the whole directory from another app and tried to run.

Comment: Same...I had copied my react app into a new folder.  I read this post, deleted my node_modules directory, ran `npm install`, and then said "voila"

Comment: I use two diff machines and Dropbox synced over the node_modules folder from one machine to other. This solution resolved it for me.

Comment: Agree. I faced the problem in the question when I converted my project into a git repository. Initiated git repository using git init . and committed and pushed my changes. Removing the nodes_module and doing npm install again worked well!

Comment: The actual problem is that a lot of ways of copying do not copy/preserve the symlinks; under linux/mac use cp -a to copy react projects and everything is fine!

Answer (score 10):

Remove node module folder
`rm -rf node_modules`

Install node modules
`npm install`

Run the project
 `npm start`

Answer (score 5):

Updating `create-react-app` fixed the issue for me.

```
npm install -g create-react-app@latest
```

Also, remember it's **not** `node start`, it's `npm start`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when working in WSL2, I copied the `reactjs-app` to home directory to WSL2. So to resolve it when working on there, delete `node_modules` and run again `npm install` inside the app directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got the answer .  The script/ folder was accidentally placed in the wrong directory it should be in the root folder of my application.
i placed it in the root folder and the app is now running as it was . thank you for your lead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue then I solved it this problem with rename root folder
name.
Remove folder name if folder name contain any symbol like
& etc. then try with this command

```
    npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

I had already tried `rm yarn.lock && rm -rf node_modules && yarn && yarn start` but it didn't work.

Eventually I realized that my project had 2 inner projects, too!

So I needed to delete the inner `yarn.lock` files and `node_modules` folders and then run `yarn && yarn start` from the outer level.

That worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by reverting my repo to a previous commit before I started getting this issue. I made sure my `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files didn't have either of the name of the modules that stopped the build from compiling. At this point, I didn't have the modules folder in the project file-structure either, indicating a clean node package. Then I did a `npm install` and the app finally compiled.

Hope that helps! Good vibes!

Here's the root cause of my issue - I was trying to install 2 packages using the `npm install <name_of_module>` command but the install kept returning errors without installing fully. I decided to go to the packages' GitHub repos and clone the files onto my rig and manually add the files as a component, add the packages files in the modules folder, and manually include the package names and versions into the `package.json` file. I did all of that and ran a `npm install` command that broke my dev environment.