# create-react-app Error: Cannot find module 'react-scripts/scripts/init.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Everytime I try to create a brand new project with create-react-app I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react-scripts/scripts/init.js'
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1zLu.png)

**THE WAY I CREATE PROJECT:**

```
npx create-react-app new-project
```

```
node -v v12.13.1
npm -v 6.12.1
OS Win10
```

**already tried:**

- `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
- different project paths

**by the way:**

- the problem disappears when I use `--use-npm` flag

Any ideas what the reason can be?

Comment: Hey Dean. create-react-app is old now. use npx create-react-app. Have provided the reasons in my answer. Do accept by answer and vote for it, if it is useful to you. That's how new questioners say thanks on Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Open your command prompt and type "node -v" as well as "npm -v", What do you get there as a response?

Comment: v12.13.1,
6.12.1

Comment: Ok, this means your node is installed correctly which is required for "npm" as well as "react".
Try to execute command "npx create-react-app appname"

Answer (score 0):

`React-scripts` issue is issue with webpack and babel mostly. You should
create a brand new project using `npx create-react-app projectName` and this is the recommended approach. This way you don't have to globally install `create-react-app` in your machine which was previous approach.

Have a look at the documentation. https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

**NOTE:**

1. For `npx create-react-app projectName`to work. Your node and npm
   should be:  Node >= 8.10 and npm >= 5.6
2. And you will have to uninstall old `create-react-app` from the
   machine. See the doc: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

Comment: yeah, this is exactly how I do it and get this error

Comment: Did you get error after creating a project using npx create-react-app. If yes thenTry 2 things.

Comment: 1) Check you node version and npm version, they should be  Node >= 8.10 and npm >= 5.6

Comment: 2) Uninstall old global create-react-app from your machine. Here you also need to manually delete some files from C:drive. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#:~:text=If%20you've%20previously%20installed,always%20uses%20the%20latest%20version.&text=Then%20open%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F%20to%20see%20your%20app.

Comment: Do one thing. Uninstalled node as well. Install a fresh node. Remember manually also delete files from C drive under program files related to node

Comment: Also may be you have yarn also installed. Just check yarn -v. Since you are saying that --use-npm works . I yarn may be messing the things up. I have encountered this also once. But whatever I did at that time. I already shared with you

Answer (score 0):

Here i found an answer to the same issue, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63334241/7857368

have your tried creating the app with `npx create-react-app myapp` you don't need to install the create-react-app globally anymore with this command.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following commands:

```
npm install
npm install react-scripts
npx create-react-app App-name
```