# I get the same error everytime I run npm start

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-start

Guys I am new to React and I get this same error every time I run the command `npm start`. Can someone please help out because I am just stuck at this. Here is the error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:939:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:780:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912342/error-cannot-find-module-react-scripts-bin-react-scripts-js)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this command and it should work for me it worked!!

For All Operating => Windows, Linux, MacO

1. Delete the node_modules directory
2. Delete the package-lock.json file
3. Run `npm install`
   If this command does not work try the below command
4. Run `npm install --save`
5. Run `npm start`

For Linux

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install && npm start
```

you can also read here about the similar error
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9954

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It shows the same error

Comment: it should work can you share your directory SS to check what's in there :) ?

Comment: Nevermind bro it worked! I had an "&" in my directory which I removed and now its working. Thanks for help tho! Stay blessed :)

Comment: That sounds good bro! you too :)

Answer (score 0):

it's becuase you must use `npm install` first to install node_modules in your project and then run the app with npm start.