# Why my react-scripts is not working in other drives than C?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I created a react app and it installed all the dependencies including react-scripts. But this giving me error "Modules not found". It is only occurring in other drives than C. In my main partition i.e. C: it's running successfully..

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZvqo.png)

```
PS D:\Learn & Practice\React\my-first-react-app> npm start

> my-first-react-app@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

'Practice\React\my-first-react-app\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v21.5.0
```

Comment: I think this error happens because of path of your project. Your project path includes specific character `&`. please check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912342/error-cannot-find-module-react-scripts-bin-react-scripts-js